# The relationship between a Command, Domain Event and Aggregate

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am new to the concept of DDD (with CQRS) so please, bare with me for this moment.

I understand what are Aggregates, Entities, Domain Events and Commands but I really have a terrible time comprehending the relationships between them.

My questions are:
Does a Command, well, command an Aggregate to do something? Or does it create entities? Or both and I have full control (and responsibility) over how I use this tool?
Does a Command emit Domain Events? If so, why and when?

I believe my question is solely based on my lack of experience in this field. Maybe a quick example would help?

Let's consider a scenario:
John wants to invite Zoe to go to the cinema with him. He sends a text message to her. She gets it and she accepts the invitation.

How would you approach this in regards of my previous question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commands are public entry-points to your application. They provide an easy way of calling your domain, which could otherwise be complicated.

> Does a Command, well, command an Aggregate to do something?

Yes.

> Or does it create entities?

Also yes.

> Or both and I have full control (and responsibility) over how I use this tool?

How you design a command is entirely up to you. E.g. a `RegisterNewUserCommand` is likely to create a new `User` entity record. But a `ChangeUserPasswordCommand` on the other hand needs an existing `User` entity record so that it can change its email, on it.

> Does a Command emit Domain Events?

No. Command, while being a somewhat domain concept, does not emit domain events. Domain events are emitted from entities (aggregates, be it). It's up to your infrastructure setup how this is done. E.g. through a static `DomainEvent.emit` call, which is kinda difficult to test, or perhaps by having your your entities implement/extend a `EventEmitter`, which in turn internally tracks a `Collection<Event> emittedEvents` and in your infrastructure you iterate those (before/after database transaction, depends on your needs) and react to those.

> Let's consider a scenario: John wants to invite Zoe to go to the cinema with him. He sends a text message to her. She gets it and she accepts the invitation.

1. You could start with an `InviteUserToEventCommand`, having a `idOfUserToBeInvited` attribute.
2. In command handler, you load a user for the currently authenticated user in your system (e.g. authenticated using a session), and you create a `UserEventInvitation`, having e.g. `invitedByUserId` and `invitedUserId`, and perhaps some other attributes which you decide to track.
3. Based on the complexity of your system, you can simply call a `TextMessageService.sendMessage` method after creation of the invitation, or you could have the invitation creation emit an `UserEventInvitationCreatedEvent`, listen to it and call the `TextMessageService.sendMessage` in an event listener (perhaps even asynchronously?).
4. Zoe decides to accept the invitation, for which you would have another command, `AcceptUserEventInvitation`, having an `userEventInvitationId`, attribute.

In simple terms, the code could look something like this:

```
interface TextMessageService {

    void sendMessage(UserId toUser, String message);
}

interface SessionService {

    User getCurrentUser();
}

interface UserService {

    User getUserById(UserId id);
}

interface UserEventInvitationRepository {

    void save(UserEventInvitation userEventInvitation);
}

interface UserEventInvitationService {

    UserEventInvitation getUserEventInvitationById(UserEventInvitationId id);
}

class UserId {

    private String value;

    private UserId(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static UserId fromString(String value) {
        return new UserId(value);
    }
}

class User {

    private UserId id;

    public UserId getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

class UserEventInvitationId {

    private String value;

    private UserEventInvitationId(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static UserEventInvitationId generateNew() {
        return new UserEventInvitationId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }

    public static UserEventInvitationId fromString(String value) {
        return new UserEventInvitationId(value);
    }
}

enum UserEventInvitationState {
    PENDING,
    ACCEPTED,
}

class UserEventInvitation {

    private UserEventInvitationId id;

    private UserId invitedByUserId;
    private UserId invitedUserId;
    private UserEventInvitationState state;

    public UserEventInvitation(User invitedByUser, User invitedUser) {
        UserId invitedByUserId = invitedUser.getId();
        UserId invitedUserId = invitedUser.getId();

        if (invitedByUserId.equals(invitedUserId)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot invite self.");
        }

        this.id = UserEventInvitationId.generateNew();

        this.invitedByUserId = invitedByUserId;
        this.invitedUserId = invitedUserId;
        this.state = UserEventInvitationState.PENDING;
    }

    public void accept(User acceptedBy) {
        if (!UserEventInvitationState.PENDING.equals(state)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Only pending invitations might be accepted.");
        }

        if (!invitedUserId.equals(acceptedBy.getId())) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not accept invitation, it's for a different user.");
        }

        state = UserEventInvitationState.ACCEPTED;
    }
}

class InviteUserToEventCommand {

    private String idOfUserToBeInvited;

    public String getIdOfUserToBeInvited() {
        return idOfUserToBeInvited;
    }
}

class InviteUserToEventCommandHandler {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final SessionService sessionService;
    private final UserEventInvitationRepository userEventInvitationRepository;
    private final TextMessageService textMessageService;

    public InviteUserToEventCommandHandler(
            UserService userService,
            SessionService sessionService,
            UserEventInvitationRepository userEventInvitationRepository,
            TextMessageService textMessageService
    ) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.sessionService = sessionService;
        this.userEventInvitationRepository = userEventInvitationRepository;
        this.textMessageService = textMessageService;
    }

    public void handle(InviteUserToEventCommand command) {
        User currentUser = sessionService.getCurrentUser();
        User userToBeInvited = userService.getUserById(UserId.fromString(command.getIdOfUserToBeInvited()));

        UserEventInvitation userEventInvitation = new UserEventInvitation(currentUser, userToBeInvited);

        userEventInvitationRepository.save(userEventInvitation);

        textMessageService.sendMessage(userToBeInvited.getId(), "You have been invited to event.");
    }
}

class AcceptUserEventInvitationCommand {

    private String userEventInvitationId;

    public String getUserEventInvitationId() {
        return userEventInvitationId;
    }
}

class AcceptUserEventInvitationCommandHandler {

    private final UserEventInvitationService userEventInvitationService;
    private final UserEventInvitationRepository userEventInvitationRepository;
    private final SessionService sessionService;

    AcceptUserEventInvitationCommandHandler(
            UserEventInvitationService userEventInvitationService,
            UserEventInvitationRepository userEventInvitationRepository,
            SessionService sessionService
    ) {
        this.userEventInvitationService = userEventInvitationService;
        this.userEventInvitationRepository = userEventInvitationRepository;
        this.sessionService = sessionService;
    }

    public void handle(AcceptUserEventInvitationCommand command) {
        UserEventInvitation toBeAccepted = userEventInvitationService.getUserEventInvitationById(
                UserEventInvitationId.fromString(command.getUserEventInvitationId())
        );

        toBeAccepted.accept(sessionService.getCurrentUser());

        userEventInvitationRepository.save(toBeAccepted);
    }
}
```